# Python Pandas Groupby averages

Tags: pandas, group-by, mean

IThis is what I currently have. I want to know what the mean is for the first time a player plays and what the mean is for the second time a player players.

| Player | Time |
| --- | --- |
| A | 5 |
| A | 8 |
| B | 7 |
| B | 12 |

I would like to know what the player's average time is the first time and the average time the second time. So the first time average would be 6 and the second time average would be 10.

Comment: I need to see if players are increasing their time on the second time playing?

Comment: A non groupby method `df.set_index(['Player',df.groupby('Player').cumcount()]).unstack().mean().droplevel(0)`

Answer (score 2):

With `groupby` + `cumcount()` we get the number of the row within each group, i.e. whether the time is for first, second, etc. per player:

```
>>> df.groupby('Player').cumcount()
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
dtype: int64
```

Reusing that in simple `groupby.mean()` we have the following solution:

```
>>> df['Time'].groupby(df.groupby('Player').cumcount()).mean()
0     6.0
1    10.0
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @Maria. Don't forget to accept the answer if this fits your need. please.